# What is the best Motor for roadtrip in Africa?

Tags: motorcycle

I am completely amateur about motors. I just want to start a road trip with a motorbike in Africa. I want to know which motor you professional recommended for this kind of trip. not very expensive, easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a novice when it comes to motorbikes but yet want to roadtrip through Africa on one? Not something i'd recommend, but fair enough: that was not your question.

For a roadtrip like that you need a reliable offroad-capable touring bike that has enough space for luggage. Good examples of those are the Honda Africa Twin and the BMW F800GS. Those bikes are used by adventurers all over the world.

Comment: Perhaps a very "simple" bike - no fancy electronics etc...

Comment: Yeah, I'm a novice. I just want to know a bike.easy to maintain. buy it. practice first for short road trip for one year. then maybe heading to Africa. not suddenly go alone. anyway thanks for recommendations .

Comment: Something else that should be taken into account is manufacturers density in the area, if you take a BMW GS to Africa and can only find Honda parts, in the event you have to repair something you're SOL.